# Change the x-axis values in MATLAB bar plot

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a bar graph in MATLAB which is plotted for 3 different variables and each of them have 9 values:

```
data = [first  second  third];
figure(1) 
hb = bar(data);
set(hb(1), 'FaceColor','r')
set(hb(2), 'FaceColor','b')
set(hb(3), 'FaceColor','g')
```

How can I have in my plot in the x-axis instead of 1-2-3..-9 my own points 50-53,60...10 (they are not increasing linearly).

Comment: Did you try `bar(x, data)`?

Comment: It seems to work but still scales everything linearly. How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
%data = [first  second  third];
data=rand(9,3)

figure(1) 
hb = bar(data);
set(hb(1), 'FaceColor','r')
set(hb(2), 'FaceColor','b')
set(hb(3), 'FaceColor','g')
set(gca,'xticklabel', {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I'})
```

`set(gca,'xticklabel', xtk_label)` could change your labels into whatever you want. See more details in [Set graphics object properties](https://cn.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/set.html?searchHighlight=set&s_tid=doc_srchtitle).